# Updating Apache configuration file on Mac

Tags: macos, apache, terminal, webserver

I am trying to set up a local web server with Apache on my Mac laptop. I have followed instructions of how to do this and I have updated the Apache conf file through terminal. I'm told that <kbd>CTRL</kbd> + <kbd>O</kbd> saves the file, but when I do this shortcut it opens my home folder to open a file.

I went to the location of the apache conf file at `/etc/apache2` but it still won't let me select the `httpd.conf` file to override it. I'm completely new to this so any help would be appreciated.

Comment: i checked terminal commands and CTRL + O is the shortcut for importing a file, that's why my folder opened up instead of saving the file. How do I save the conf file?

Comment: With which command do you edit the file?

Comment: i just realised I was pressing CMD + O instead of CTRL + O, stupid mistake

Answer (score 0):

I know that Mac has it's own apache server but I still install and use [XAMPP](https://www.apachefriends.org/index.html). It is easier to work with.